# What is the analogous way to handle pipe and subscribe for a firebase Query object?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a service in Angular with the following method that fetches data from Firebase:

```
getMatchesFiltered(matchId: string, filter: string, sortDirection: string, pageIndex: number, pageSize: number){
    return this.db.object('/matches');
  }
```

It returns a firebase Observable to which I can apply `pipe` and `subscribe`, e.g.,

```
this.dbService.getMatchesFiltered(matchId, filter, sortDirection, pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(
                    catchError(()=> of([])),
                    finalize(()=>this.loadingMatches.next(false))
                  )
                  .subscribe(matches => {
                    let results = [];
                    let json_data = matches;
                    for(var i in json_data){
                      if(json_data[i].matchDeets){
                        results.push([i, json_data[i].matchDeets][1]);
                      }
                    }
                    this.matchesSubject.next(results);
                  });
```

However, when I try instead to return a Query from the database service, the object returned is no longer an Observable:

```
getMatchesFiltered(matchId: string, filter: string, sortDirection: string, pageIndex: number, pageSize: number){
    let ref = firebase.database().ref("/matches");
    return ref.limitToFirst(pageSize);
  }
```

> ERROR in src/app/matchDataSource.model.ts(29,106): error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Query'

The documentation does not seem to be very forthcoming about how to handle a query in a way analogous to an observable.

For instance, I could do stuff after receiving a DataSnapshot a la:

```
ref.orderByKey().endAt("pterodactyl").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

But does that mean I'd have to add the `.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {});` part in my component, rather than keeping it nicely wrapped in the service?

So, I guess I have the following issues:

1. I don't know how to properly compartmentalize/encapsulate this.
2. I don't know how to handle what the pipe command is doing with a query from the component.ts file if I must resort to that.
3. I don't know whether I'm missing some very easy and straightfoward way to make a query behave analogously to an Observable.

Happy to provide working example from github if need be.

Comment: have you thought about using the [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/) wrapper?

Comment: @PierreDuc I have. I think this is a great lead. However, the I get FirebaseListFactoryOps errors similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651674/argument-of-type-query-limittolast-number-orderbykey-boolean-is?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
It looks like I can fix that by updating angularfire2 to v.5.x.x. However, when I run npm outdated, it seems that the WANTED version for angularfire2 in my project is 4.0.0-rc0. I'm thinking about posting a second question to resolve this.

Comment: wanted version is what's stated in your `package.json`. If you run `npm i angularfire2@latest`, it should update your package.json as wel. If you do not want to use angularfire, you can write your own wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woudn;t it be possible to put it in an Observable:

```
Observable.create(function(observer) {
    ref.orderByKey().endAt("pterodactyl").on("child_added", snapshot => 
    {
        observer.next(snapshot.key);
    });
};
```